# Typing third-party library with require('./lib').default

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a [`dynamic-cdn-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/mastilver/dynamic-cdn-webpack-plugin), however I'm a bit stuck. In the library the module is exported as `module.exports = require('./lib').default;`
With my typings I get:

> error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

```
declare module "dynamic-cdn-webpack-plugin" {
  import * as webpack from "webpack";
  interface Options {
    disable?: boolean;
    env?: string;
    exclude?: string[];
    only?: string[];
    verbose?: boolean;
    resolver?: () => {
      name: string;
      var: string;
      url: string;
      version: string;
    };
  }
  export class DynamicCdnWebpackPlugin extends webpack.Plugin {
    constructor(options?: Options);
  }
}
```

If I change that to `export default class` then I get

> Emit skipped

My guess is that I have to somehow indicate that `DynamicCdnWebpackPlugin` is the default export from that library, but I can't figure a way to do it

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: It occurs when I'm using plugin in webpack.config.ts like so:
new DynamicCdnWebpackPlugin()

Comment: In webpack.config.ts, what does the import of DynamicCdnWebpackPlugin look like?

Comment: `import DynamicCdnWebpackPlugin from "dynamic-cdn-webpack-plugin";`

Comment: It looks like the `export default class` is correct from the type checking point of view.  Is the "Emit skipped" an error message that comes from running Webpack on your project after webpack.config.ts has been successfully compiled?  If so, that's a Webpack-related problem that I won't be able to help with, and we should add the webpack tag to the question.

Comment: You are correct it was a webpack problem after all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a webpack problem after all. I took a look at webpack docs, and found that you have to use commonjs module system for `ts-node`, otherwise it will fail. The solution for me is to use `tsconfig-paths` where I can specify to use es modules for everything but webpack.config file.